# Wordpress index.php 403 Forbidden

Tags: wordpress

After installing Wordpress on my hosting I have a 403 Forbidden Error. Hosting address: [link][1]

I downloaded the Wordpress zipfile from official website change config file with my database info and transfer everything via FTP.

At first I will get to the auto-install file and I can connect to the WP-Admin by connecting to http://112.74.201.74/2016/blog/wp-admin/index.php

If I don't add index.php but only blog/ I can not connect to admin area.

Anyone have idea why I can not access to visit view of my wordpress?

I use PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 Mysql  5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: Providing the address and later specifying that it has a `403 Forbidden problem` is misleading. Please either remove the address or specify it beforehand that the error is there!

Comment: I ma not able to access admin http://112.74.201.74/2016/blog/wp-admin/ as well.

Comment: @Milap actually you can if you add index.php http://112.74.201.74/2016/blog/wp-admin/index.php but I can not connect to blog/index.php

Comment: @AvijitGupta I did not really understand what you mean. I installed Wordpress on http://112.74.201.74/2016/blog/ I can connect to 112.74.201.74/2016/blog/wp-admin/index.php but I can not access to my blog 112.74.201.74/2016/blog/index.php I will get a 403 Forbidden

Comment: @ChinaXiaoHong , what is there in your .htaccess file ? is it writable ?

Comment: @Milap I add same . htaccess file than suggested in WordPress website https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess subfolder but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution :-

- Login into backend.
- Go to [wp-admin/options-permalink.php](http://112.74.201.74/2016/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php)
- Select any of the option from **Common Settings**.
- Save Changes.

Did you get the success message as : **Permalink structure updated.** If yes try to access front end.it should work.

If you are not able to update .htaccess from backend, manually edit it from FTP and add code as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

If none of the above solution worked, contact your hosting provider, they can help you.

Comment: Thank you Milap, I did exactly what you proposed me. I got Permaling structure updated but still can not access it from front end. Actually I did not have .htaccess in my subfolder therefore I add it. However, still not working...I will therefore ask my hosting provider. Thanks

Comment: @ChinaXiaoHong, you do not need .htaccess file into subfolder. .htaccess file must be there at root and it should be updated as wordpress need.

Comment: Ok, I did put in the root and same issue. 2016 does not start well for me